# JavaScript Works in Development, Not in Production (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets

So I just pushed an app to Heroku, and JavaScript and jQuery are not working for me.

Have looked at a bunch of solutions for this but none seem to be work.

I have precompiled my assets, and I can see in Firebug that some of the functions I have declared in some of my js files in the assets folder are loading but some are not.

Edit: Just added a very simple alert function which works just fine.

Images are loading fine, styles are loading fine. Have rails_12factor gem and have run bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of debugging?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What errors are in the browser console? Are there any 404 responses in the network tab?

Comment: I have three jQuery plugins, none of which are working. I also have some JavaScript to validate a form which is not working either. In terms of the JavaScript form validation, I am getting "Is not a function" error when trying to run it. In terms of the jQuery plugins, I cannot tell why they are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was getting this error;

'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'f.msie')

which was resulting from one of the plugins using $.browser which has since been removed.

Installed jQuery migrate gem, re-pushed code, all jQuery and javascript now works.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to look this over.